# long not enough to store an integer

Tags: java, long-integer

```
public class SDO 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SDO sdo = new SDO();
        System.out.println(sdo.amountOfData(1));       
        System.out.println(sdo.amountOfData(86400));  
    }

    public long amountOfData(int seconds)
    {
        long result =  (4096*4096*seconds);
        return result;
    }

}
```

This code is returning in my test, error: amountData(1000) expected:<16777216000> but was:<-402653184>. Shouldn't type **long** store even higher integers? or if not how to make this code working ?

Comment: Please show the corresponding unit test, that results in this error message. You might want to write 4096L to force a type promotion, otherwise the expression will be calculated as an int.

Comment: an `int * int * int` is still an `int`.  The fact you assign it to a `long` means it overflows first, then gets cast to a long.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
long result = (4096*4096*seconds);
```

to

```
long result =  (4096L*4096L*seconds);
```

in order to get a `long` result and avoid `int` overflow.

`4096*4096*seconds` is a multiplication of 3 `int`s, and results in an `int`, which may overflow before being assigned to your `long` variable.

Answer (score 6):

With:

```
long result =  (4096*4096*seconds);
```

`result` can indeed hold the value, but the *calculation* is being done exclusively with `int` types, because it's performing arithmetic on exclusively `int`s.

So the *result* of the expression will be an `int`, and you'll later place that into the `long` but *not* before you've lost information.

You can coerce Java into using `long` for the *intermediate* result simply by making the first constant a `long`:

```
long result =  4096L * 4096 * seconds;
```

though it may be more prudent to make them all longs so as to make your intent clearer.

This is covered in the Java Language Spec:

> Numeric promotion is applied to the operands of an arithmetic operator. Numeric promotion contexts allow the use of an identity conversion, a **widening primitive conversion,** or an unboxing conversion.
>
> Numeric promotions are used to convert the operands of a numeric operator to a **common type** so that an operation can be performed. The two kinds of numeric promotion are unary numeric promotion and binary numeric promotion.

One *other* solution is to let the function call itself widen the data type, with something like:

```
public long amountOfData (long seconds) {
    return seconds * 4096 * 4096;
}
```

This will have a similar effect since `seconds` will now be a `long` so the calculation will be done as a `long`. It will also shorten your code a little.